# Getting System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object in test class. I am getting error in Apex class while querying the Account

Tags: apex, unit-test

```java
public class AP20Case{
    public Static Void UpdateAccOwner(List<Account> AccList){
        List<Account> Acc = [Select id, RecordTypeId from Account where Id IN :Trigger.newMap.keyset() and (Account.RecordType.Name = 'Company(TA EPN)' OR Account.RecordType.Name = 'Company(FMC)' OR Account.RecordType.Name = 'Company(Non Funds)')];
        if(Acc.size() > 0){
            for(Account A : AccList){
                if(A.NetwrkRelatshpMgr__c != NULL){
                    system.debug('*##Account Recordtype Number##*'+A.RecordTypeID);
                    A.OwnerId = A.NetwrkRelatshpMgr__c;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Trigger

```java
trigger Account_BI_BU on Account (before insert, before update) {
    if(PAD.Cantrigger('AP20')){
        system.debug('*##AP20 Start##*');
        if(Trigger.IsBefore){
            system.debug('*##AP20 IsBefore##*');
            if(Trigger.IsInsert || Trigger.IsUpdate ){
                system.debug('*##AP20 IF IsInsert or IsUpdate##*');
                for(Account Acc :Trigger.New){
                    system.debug('*##AP20 For##*');
                    if(Trigger.IsInsert && Acc.NetwrkRelatshpMgr__c != NULL){
                        Acc.addError('Network Manager should be blank on creation of Company');
                        break;
                    }
                    else if(Acc.NetwrkRelatshpMgr__c != NULL && (Acc.NetwrkRelatshpMgr__c !=  trigger.oldmap.get(Acc.id).NetwrkRelatshpMgr__c)){
                       system.debug('*##AP20 final if##*');
                       AP20Case.UpdateAccOwner(Trigger.New);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Test Class

```java
@isTest
public static void AP20Test2(){
    Profile p = [SELECT Id, Name from Profile where Name = 'network Manager ' LIMIT 1];
        
    User objUser1 = new User(Alias = 'Paved', Email='yaa@eu.com.invalid', 
        EmailEncodingKey='UTF-8', LastName='Ved', LanguageLocaleKey='en_US', 
        LocaleSidKey='en_US', ProfileId = p.Id, UserRoleId= role.Id,
        TimeZoneSidKey='America/Los_Angeles', UserName='P1ra2Ved1@testrg.com');
             
    insert objUser1;           
            
    System.runAs(objUser1){
        // UpdateAccountOwner
        List<RecordType> AccRecType = [SELECT Id, Name from RecordType where sObjectType = 'Account' AND Name = 'Company(TA EPN)' LIMIT 1];
        Account a1 = new Account (name = 'Test1', RecordTypeId = AccRecType[0].Id);
        insert a1;
        a1.NetwrkRelatshpMgr__c = objUser1.id;
        update a1;
        List<Account> acclist1 = new List<Account>();
        acclist1.add(a1);
                 
        Test.startTest();             
        AP20Case.UpdateAccOwner(acclist1);           
        Test.stopTest();
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Trigger context variables are only populated when you're running code because of a trigger.

In your test, `AP20Test2`, you're calling `AP20Case.UpdateAccOwner()` directly. That's generally how you want to structure your tests, but it does mean that you won't have access to `Trigger.new`, `Trigger.newMap`, `Trigger.old`, etc...

So that's the source of your issue.
Your query is `List<Account> Acc = [Select id, RecordTypeId from Account where Id IN :Trigger.newMap.keyset() ...`, and `Trigger.newMap` is null.

You shouldn't be using `Trigger.newMap.keyset()` *anywhere* in `UpdateAccOwner()`. The entire reason why you (or someone else, perhaps?) included the `List<Account>` as a parameter in that method signature is so that you can *use that instead of relying on trigger context variables*.

You should be able to replace `Trigger.newMap.keyset()` with `AccList` (I believe Salesforce still allows `Id IN :<list of SObject>` as "syntactic sugar"). If not though, you can simply create a new Map inside of that method and pass your List of Accounts in as an argument to the constructor (after which you would be able to use `Id IN :myMap.keySet()`)

#### Other notes

- You should learn how to use whitespace. It's not a syntax error (in this case), but it will likely make other people think that you're not experienced in programming/your skill level is low. The most common mistake here is not putting space between an operator and its operands (i.e. `2+2` is bad, and `2 + 2` is good)
- You should learn about "code style". Adhering to a style, and being consistent with it makes code easier to read. A common code style includes things like

  - variables should start with a lowercase letter (a.k.a. "camelCase")
  - collections should have plural names (e.g. `List<Account> myAccounts`)
  - be consistent with where the braces go for classes, methods, `if` and `else`, `for` loops, etc... (K&R style is what I edited your question to be, Allman style is the other main style)
  - always indent one extra level when you encounter an opening curly brace
- You do not need to check `if(Acc.size() > 0){` before looping over that list. If a list is empty, the loop will simply not be executed